# Launch image in landscape is not enabled?

Tags: xcode

Something strange happens with `Xcode`. 
We have universal app, that we would like to set up launch image only for landscape.(the app is in landscape.)

So, in the launch screen file, on the right side, i can choose :

```
   iOS8 and later:
   -iPhone portrait
   -iPhone landscape

    iOS7 and later:
    -iPhone portrait
    -iPad portrait
    -iPad landscape
```

on `iOS8` when you choose *landscape*- it shows **only** `retina HD 5.5`. but where is the landscape for all other devices in iOS8 ??

Its simple. we have landscape images, and we would like to load them to ALL  devices, in all their shapes and versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there has never been a separate landscape launch image for iPhone. The portrait launch image for iPhone is used, rotated, as the landscape launch image if the app launches in landscape. Thus, for iPhone, you only need portrait launch images.

Moreover, "iOS 7 and later" includes iOS 8 (because that is what "later" means). Thus, between them, "iOS 7 and later" and "iOS 8" provide slots for enough portrait launch images to cover all iPhone devices.

But, as you have rightly noted, the iPhone 6 plus is exceptional. It behaves like an iPad - it *can* have a separate landscape launch image. So that is the only separate iPhone landscape launch image slot provided. It is provided under "iOS 8" because iPhone 6 plus doesn't run iOS 7.